# Ivory Headgear--Likely or Not?

Tags: science-based, materials, alternate-earth, mammals

[image]

My apologies for not giving you a larger image, but it does show you a compare-and-contrast on what horn is in comparison to what antler is.  Basically, it's just a piece of bone covered in softer material.  That is pretty much it in regards to mammalian headgear--either horn or antler, you can't have both.

But what about ivory, the material that back home can be found in the tusks of elephants, walruses and narwhals?  In an alternate Earth, could ivory make a good material to wear on an ungulate's head for rutting?

Comment: Seeing as tusks are used for similar purposes to cervine rutting, I would think 'yes'...

Comment: the main issue with ivory is they are teeth so the question is how to get them on top of hte head.

Comment: Just make the upper canines of (otherwise) herbivores grow upwards from their buds into some form of tusks.
Genetic accident at first, if it provides a mating advantage, it will become a permanent fixture.

Comment: Why are you asking? Two elephants jousting with their tusks seems to prove that they'd be as well suited for the top of the head as the lower jaw (ignoring how it comes to pass...). The only disadvantage I can think of is that ivory's honking heavy compared to, e.g., antlers. I remember Angelina Jolie saying that headdress' weight in *Maleficent* would bring her to tears. Your critter had better have serious muscles and vertebrae.

Answer (score 3):

Ivory is a modified form of dentine, and in mammals occurs only in teeth (elephants, walruses, elk, warthogs, etc.) There is no known instance of any kind of dental tissue (enamel, ivory, etc.) growing directly from the heads of mammals. In all cases where you have a protruding ivory tissue it is a modified tooth, and all horns, ossicones, antlers, etc. of mammals are made of cranial bone, not teeth. The best you could probably do is have a pair of teeth grow upwards through the skull, as in the [babirusa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babirusa). Even so, these structures would still be teeth, not horns.

Comment: @JBH It *does* answer OP's question "Ivory Headgear--Likely or Not?": Not, because ivory is a dental tissue and horns are always made of bone or keratin whether it is mammals, reptiles, or fish. There is no known example in nature of teeth growing out of the skullcap instead of the mouth. The example you listed are teratomas, which are non-functional tumors that cannot be inherited. You could have tusks, but based on OP's question they don't consider elephant or narwhal tusks to be "headgear".

Comment: @JBH the babirusa example for the possible mechanism getting ivory *horn-like structures* ("a pair of teeth grow upwards through the skull") does provide an answer the question of "how  could ivory make a good material to wear on an ungulate's head for rutting?" I tend to ascribe everything else into "pedantry in using the appropriate terminology", which isn't such a mortal sin.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi OP didn't seem to consider tusks to be "headgear" because they didn't seem to consider the existence of narwhals, elephants, etc. to answer their question. They appear to want cranial growths like horns or antlers. *I* would consider tusks to be "headgear", and therefore elephants would be an acceptable answer (they do the same things with them anyway) but I am not the one defining the question.

Comment: `want cranial growths like horns or antlers.` I couldn't find such cases either on the Earth fauna, though I don't think it's impossible in an `alternate-earth` context. And that is where your answer is too strict (i.e. considering the current Earth's reality). - to be ctnd

Comment: (ctnd) ... other examples of "not headgear tusks": [fanged deer](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/news/2014/12/141224-deer-fanged-vampire-animals-science-krampus-christmas/) (note the "smaller deer retained the tusks but kept small antlers") and [why it is so](https://www.nationalgeographic.co.uk/animals/2018/11/how-animals-got-their-tusks-horns-and-antlers) ("They have a fighting style where they will fence a bit with their antlers and try to flip their opponent’s head up and then come in and slash their opponent with the tusks," - clearly an advantage used during rut)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Horns have repeatedly evolved numerous times in tetrapods (chameleons, phrynosomatids, horned frogs, vipers, ceratopsids, abelisaurs, independently at least seven times in ungulates, etc.) and every time they are either keratin and/or bone and never dental tissues. There may be reasons for this, developmentally the braincase (dermatocranium) and mouthparts (splanchnocranium) come from two very different places, but the fact that horns are consistently bone or keratin despite their convergent origin suggests constraint or it's just easier to make bone/keratin horns...

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi You could say "it's an alternate Earth, anything could happen for the sake of the story", but it would be at odds with what is currently known about how horns evolve and develop, much like handwaving a functional six-legged mammal with HOX gene mutations when HOX genes do not work that way (see answers to [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/15156/evolving-another-pair-of-limbs/74233?r=SearchResults#74233)).